# Android app wont open on tablet, but will in emulator

Tags: android

When I export my app its all fine and good until I look at the size... its 176kb and that doesnt seem big enough to me, that was my first sign somthing was going wrong, then when I put the app on my Galaxy tab, and click intal it wouldnt open. The same thing happens on the emulator, when you click on the app icon a toast will come up saying "this app is not installed". HOWEVER! If I wait a couple seconds to let the emulator open the app by its self it will all run perfectly? any help for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to say whats wrong. But  after an successful installation to the emulator a apk is located in the bin folder this apk should work it is the same as the one  installed to the emulator